# Bug with the responsive design of website

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, responsive

I made this site about Java Tutorials in Bulgarian, but I have a bug with the responsive design. When I open it on another device with difference width and height, it becomes very bad.I tried to solve it and i think the main problem is with the margins, but i still don't know how to solve it. Please, help me.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Language, title, link, meta-->
    <lang="bg"></lang>
    <title>Vayloan - Научи Java онлайн</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index-style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="css/img/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="keywords" content="vayloan, java, tutorials, free">
    <meta name="application-name" content="vayloan">
    <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="889BFB699C71E48B63966D2F50B87678" />
    <meta name="author" content="hristo todorov, yanis yakimov">
    <meta name="description" content="Vayloan е безплатна платформа, с помощта на която можеш да се научиш да програмираш на Java">
</head>
<body>
    <!--Header with navigation tab-->
    <div id="header">
        <nav>
            <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="css/img/logo.png" width="80px" height="80px"></a>
            </div>
            <ul>

                <li><a href="index.html">Начало</a></li>
                <li><a href="lessons.html">Уроци</a></li>
                <li><a href="exercises.html">Упражнения</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact-us.html">Свържете се с нас</a></li>
            </ul>

    </nav>
    </div>
    <!--Transperent background with name and slogan-->
    <div id="header-desc">
        <div id="trans">
        <!--Blank space-->
        <div id="blank-1">
        </div>
        <h1>Vayloan</h1>
        <h2>Научи Java онлайн</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Another blank space-->
    <div id="another-bs">
    </div>
    <!--Main content-->
    <div id="content">
        <div id="question">
        <strong>Какво е Vayloan?</strong>
        </div>
        <div id="answer">
            Vayloan е образователна платформа, която ще Ви помогне да научите Java бързо и лесно.
    <br>
    <br>
    Ето с какво Vayloan се различава от другите образователни платформи:
        </div>
        <div id="why">
            <img src="css/img/check.png" id="check"> 
            <div id="check-text-1">
                <strong>Кратки и лесноразбираеми видео уроци на български</strong>
            </div>  

            <br>
            <br>
            <img src="css/img/check.png" id="check"> 
            <div id="check-text-2">
               <strong>Упражнения, с които да затвърдите новите знания</strong> 
            </div>

            <br>
            <br>
            <img src="css/img/check.png" id="check"> 
            <div id="check-text-3">
                <strong>Можете да задавате въпроси и да давате предложения</strong>  
            </div>

            <br>
            <br>
            <img src="css/img/check.png" id="check"> 
            <div id="check-text-4">
                <strong>Видео уроци, както за начинаещи така и за напреднали</strong>
            </div>


            <br>         
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Footer-->
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="bs">
        </div>
        <h6>Copyright &copy; 2018 | Изработен от Христо Тодоров и Янис Якимов | Проект №84 за НОИТ</h6>
        <div id="contact">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Vayloan-1951527885163461/"><img src="css/img/fb.png"></a>
            <a href="https://github.com/Vayloan"><img src="css/img/github.png"></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWt3DkdlMsordyw967G1akg"><img src="css/img/yt.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-size: 40pt;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
#header-desc {
background-image: url(img/header-bg.jpg);
height: 760px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
}
 body {
margin: 0 auto;
}
#blank-1 {
height: 280px;
}
h2 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 25pt;
color: white;
font-family: cursive;
}
#trans {
height: 760px;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40); 
}
#header {
height: 80px;
background-color: #011222;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
ul li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
line-height: 100px;
margin-top: -99px;
margin-left: 80px;
}
ul li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: arial;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 0px;
}

#footer {
background-color: #011222;
height: 250px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-size: 17pt;
}
#bs {
height: 100px;
}
#contact {
float: right;
margin-right: 50px;
}
h3 {
text-align:center;
font-size: 27pt;
}

#bs-2 {
height: 30px;
}
#content {
height:655px;
background-image: url(img/contact-bg.png);
}
#another-bs {
height:100px;
background-image: url(img/contact-bg.png);
}
#logo {
margin-left: 10px;
}
#question {
text-align: center;
font-size: 28pt;
font-family: monospace;
}
#answer {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 30px;
font-size: 20pt;
font-family: cursive;
}
#why {
margin-top: 40px;
margin-left: 20%;
font-size: 22pt;
margin-right: 21.63%;

}
#check-text-1 {
float: right;  
margin-right:12.26%;
margin-top: 5px;

}
#check-text-2 {
float: right;
margin-right:17.34%;
margin-top: 5px;
}
#check-text-3 {
float: right;
margin-right:12%;
margin-top: 5px;
}
#check-text-4 {
float: right;   
margin-right: 9.5%;
margin-top: 5px;
}
a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #3ab913;
}

a:active {
text-decoration: none;

}
```

GITHUB: https://github.com/Vayloan/Vayloan.github.io

Answer (score 0):

As to the responsiveness of your design, there are many factors that cause issues, such as the use of pixels in height/width instead of %. If you want certain things to be bigger or smaller based on the size of the screen, you should learn about [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

If you have a more specific question that I can answer I'm happy to help, but this is not the place for asking very broad questions like "my design is bad, please help me fix the problem".

---

Always have the viewport meta tag for responsive websites to adjust for different screen sizes:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) how it works and why it is important.

---

Also, this is not a valid tag:

```
<lang="bg"></lang>
```

Put the language attribute in your html tag, like so:

```
<html lang="bg">
```